# Reading specific data from a text file

Tags: python

I have a .dat file that contains over 40,000 lines containing text and data. I want to extract specific data from this file according to the following:

I need a line counter, obviously, so I know when I reach the end of the file. 
I want to open the file for reading and another for writing, and read the first line. If the line 2 positions from the first line begins with "Model", I want to print a blank line to the file open for writing and then skip two lines ahead in the file. If the line two positions from the opening line does not start with "Model", then I wish to select the text that is 8 positions from this first line and print that to the file opened for writing. I will then move 11 positions from the first line and so on.

```
infile = open("ratios.dat","r")
outfile = open("corr_ratios.txt","w")

for aline in infile:
    items = (aline+2).split()
    if items[0] = "Model"
        outfile.write("\n")
        aline = aline+2
    else    
        items = aline+8
        outfile.write(items)
```

Comment: A for-loop using "aline" as the counter (could be wrong here). On reading the file, I split the line so that the first position items[0](where items = aline.split()) is checked for whether it is equal to "Model". If not, i copy the data 8 lines down from the first one read, and write the contents to the other opened file. I haven't tested it, all on paper as I write this - just needed other python programmer's views...

Comment: you should post the code that you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in python are their own iterators and can be worked with / advanced a line at a time like so:

```
with open('path-to-file.txt') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    # code here to deal with line.
```

Additionally, because the file handle is an iterator, it can be advanced explicitly as well:

```
with open('path-to-file.txt') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    if condition:
      # skip a line
      next(infile)
```

Combining the two, you should be able to use lines, skip lines, etc.

Having reviewed your posted code closer, you're attempting to add an integer to a string (`aline + 2`).  To come closer to your attempted approach, you'd actually do something like this:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
for lineno, line in enumerate(lines):
  targetline = lines[lineno + 2]
```

This approach loads the entire file into memory, which may or may not be suitable depending on your file size.

Comment: I tried writing something with your above suggestions. However, seeing as line is essentially a string, it is difficult to see how you can skip several lines using "line" unless you had an integer index increasing each time you read.

Comment: Each time the `for` loop runs you consume one line in the file.  Each time you call `next(infile)` you consume another.  `for _ in range(4): next(infile)` skips four lines.

Comment: I understand this. However, I want to have a reference line from which I test the values on some succeeding lines (in this case two lines ahead). It is based on the content of the succeeding lines that I make the next move, i.e. 2 spaces or 11 spaces ahead. Many thanks for your advice.